# How to start application before all eunit cases

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, rebar, eunit

My Erlang project managed by rebar, it divides to different module.

```
-pro
  |-- rel
  |-- src
  |-- test
     |--- module1_tests.erl
     |--- module2_tests.erl
```

and for each module*_tests.erl, Use Eunit [Fixtures](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Fixtures) to setup environment. For example,

```
module1_test_() ->
    {setup,
        fun setup/0,
        fun clean_up/1,
        fun (SetupData) ->
            [
                test_function(SetupData)
            ]
    end}.

setup() ->
    pro:start(),
    ok.

clean_up(_) ->
    pro:stop().
```

And Makefile is:

```
test:
    ERL_AFLAGS="-config rel/pro/etc/app.config"  $(REBAR)  compile eunit skip_deps=true
```

Here I encounter a problem, since I have many test module in test/, each test module will start and stop application for whole executing flow. Sometimes start application will be failed, told not find app.config configure file, not sure why.

So I think is there a way to start application before all test module?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you performing kind of testing that far away from `unit testing` idea. Maybe, in this case, you should use [common test framework](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/basics_chapter.html)?

Answer (score 1):

From Erlang docs -config flag you used
(ERL_AFLAGS="-config rel/pro/etc/app.config")
has to be
ERL_AFLAGS="-config app"

Answer (score 1):

Look at Fixtures: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Fixtures

A quick and dirty way could also be to add something like this as the first test case.

```erlang
init_test() ->
  {ok, Apps} = application:ensure_all_started(myapp),
```